# Redirecting logged out users from specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website, its using buddypress and bbpress. I need to hide/redirect all the buddypress and bbpress pages from people who are not logged in. So if someone lands on the members page, profile page or any forum topic it needs to redirect them to the signup page.

I tried maybe 5 plugins, all of them caused issues like 404 errors, not working or just white pages.

The url structure is like this:

```
www.example.com/members
www.example.com/members/luke
www.example.com/forums
www.example.com/forums/forum/general-chat
```

Does anyone know how I can do this without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `theme/functions.php` or in [bp-custom.php](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/bp-custom-php/):

```
function lukedi_private_check() {

    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || bp_is_register_page() || bp_is_activation_page() )
            return;

        $redirect_url = trailingslashit( site_url() );  // change this to whatever you need

        // member page
        if ( bp_is_user() )  
            bp_core_redirect( $redirect_url );

        // bbPress
        if( is_bbpress() ) 
            bp_core_redirect( $redirect_url );

        // members loop
        $bp_current_component = bp_current_component();

        if ( false != $bp_current_component ) {

            if ( 'members' == $bp_current_component )
                bp_core_redirect( $redirect_url );

        }

    }
}
add_action( 'bp_ready', 'lukedi_private_check' );
```

Comment: This gave my website a white page, php error somewhere maybe?

Comment: Sorry, extra bracket. Edited and fixed.  And you'll need to adjust the redirect url to point to whatever you want. Currently goes to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify from within a child theme the profile-loop.php file

```
your-child-theme/members/single/profile/profile-loop.php
```

On the first line of the file, add

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in()  ) : ?>
```

At the end of the file, insert between the last endif and the last do_action this:

```
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo “<div style=’width: 600px;height:25px; padding: 4px; border: 3px solid #ff0000; text-align: center; font-style:bold; font-size: 1.3em;’> You must be logged in to view a member profile</div>”; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Change the div inline style to whatever you need accordingly to your theme. The example fits with bp-default.

If you can not do that, then try this plugin,
[plugin](http://buddydev.com/buddypress/bp-redirect-to-profile-plugin-redirect-users-to-their-profile-on-login-on-buddypress-sites/)

Try this but make sure to change the url to what you want

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or i.d here') && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is what I want. I dont want to redirect to anyone's profile. I want non logged in users to be redirected to a signup page if they try access specific pages like above.

Comment: yes. So you need to add my answer to the pages you have to be logged in to see. then redirect them to where ever you want.

Comment: I think that is a better option personally

Comment: @wuno Thanks, I will give that bit you added at the bottom a go. :)

Comment: No problem. If I helped you please accept my answer.

Comment: I just tried this and it did nothing, I add it to my childs functions.php I tried using the url and the slug, my code looked like this     http://pastebin.com/JbZs0SEG